# java.util.NoSuchElementException when using prev() on Iterator but no errors on next()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a video player in my android app, and I have a prev and next buttons. However the prev button gives this error:

> 02-26 07:15:11.519 32576-32576/com.example.espina.momshie
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.espina.momshie, PID: 32576
>                                                                               java.util.NoSuchElementException
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.AbstractList$FullListIterator.previous(AbstractList.java:130)
>                                                                                   at com.Welcome.Video$3.onClick(Video.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5647)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

When I implemented the two objects prev() and next() the same way with the iterators, here's my code:

```
   Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            CheckBox chck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            ListIterator listIterator = listA.listIterator();
            ListIterator listIterator1 = listB.listIterator();


            public void onClick(View v) {


                    Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(listIterator.next()));
                    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                    videoView.start();
                    String text = String.valueOf(listIterator1.next());
                    textView4.setText(text);





            }
        });



        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            ListIterator listIterator = listA.listIterator();
            ListIterator listIterator1 = listB.listIterator();


            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(listIterator.previous()));
                    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                    videoView.start();
                    String text = String.valueOf(listIterator1.previous());
                    textView4.setText(text);





            }
        });
```

Error come from the line:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(listIterator.previous()));
```

What am I doing wrong here with using the iterators? ANy help is appreciated thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating 2 instances of the iterator, one for each button.  So when you press prev, you're trying to go to index -1.  This crashes you. You need to do 2 things:

1)Use the same iterators for both buttons.

2)For safety, always check hasPrevious before calling previous, (same for hasNext and next) so you don't go beyond the list in either direction.

Optional for real usability

3)Whenever you change the iterator, call next.setEnabled(iterator.hasNext()) and prev.setEnabled(iterator.hasPrevious()) so that buttons that won't work are disabled.

4)Use StateListDrawables for the 2 buttons so the disabled buttons gray out automatically.

Comment: Thank you @Gabe this worked, however I'm confused on the instruction 3 and 4. What I know is setting the buttons after mouse click such as this:
http://prntscr.com/ijqwno, but how do I do number 4?

Answer (score 0):

We need to check if previous/next element exists using [hasPrevious](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#hasPrevious()) and [hasNext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#hasNext()) in the list before actually accessing it to avoid java.util.NoSuchElementException